# How to cumsum two models related by an intermediate model using Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

## Problem

Let's say I have one table called **Price** which is a timeseries with a timestamp, a value and the difference of previous day. To simplify the table I have put only the dates not the hours, mins, etc.:

| timestamp | value | difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-21 | 500 | 500 |
| 2021-01-22 | 1000 | 500 |
| 2021-01-23 | 1500 | 500 |
| 2021-01-24 | 2000 | 500 |
| 2021-01-25 | 2500 | 500 |

Those values might be incorrect and a user might correct it at any point in time using a second table called **CorrectedPrice**. A user can correct the start value even before the date of the first Price value:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-15 | 1000 |
| 2021-01-23 | 500 |

By merging those two informations the resulting queryset between date 2021-01-21 and 2021-01-26 should be:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-21 | 1500 |
| 2021-01-22 | 2000 |
| 2021-01-23 | 1000 |
| 2021-01-24 | 1500 |
| 2021-01-25 | 2000 |

## Django Models

We have a **Stock** model:

```py
class Stock(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.Charfield(unique=True)
```

A **Price** model:

```py
class Price(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    difference = models.IntegerField()  # done with a signal on pre_save
    timestamp = AutoCreatedField()
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and then we have the **CorrectedPrice** model:

```py
class CorrectedPrice(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = AutoCreatedField()
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

## What I tried

```py
start_date = ... # 2021-01-21
end_date = ... # 2021-01-26

Price.objects.filter(
    name=stock_name, 
    timestamp__range(start_date, end_date)
).annotate(
    value=Window(Sum("difference"), order_by=F("timestamp").asc()),
    timestamp=F("timestamp")
)
```

Which basically does not take into account the **CorrectedPrice** table. I managed to add a constant after `value=Window(Sum("difference"), order_by=F("timestamp").asc())` as such `value=Window(Sum("difference"), order_by=F("timestamp").asc()) + 1` but this will only take into account one value.

How can one solve this issue and have the results shown in the third table ? Is the Django ORM able to do this in a proper way?

Comment: Why are you using the sum of the difference to compute the value if it is already stored as a column? In fact, if you try to add an annotation with the same name as an existing field, the ORM will raise an exception that your annotation conflicts with a field on the model.

Comment: I thought that using the difference might be easier for queries. If a user sets the corrected price to 100 and if the difference is 200 then we know that we have to add 100+200. Instead of looking back to what was the value of the price on the previous day in the query itself. What alternative solution do you propose ?

Comment: First, storing the value and the difference is redundant. One can always be calculated from the other. My preference would be to store the value and calculate the difference when I need it, but your application might have considerations that make storing the difference better. Second, I don't get your explanation of why you're computing the value using the difference. If the user corrects the price, is that supposed to affect all following prices?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to affect all following prices but the computation might be intensive as such that it will require a worker to do it until the most recent data. Furthermore, a user might change the price when a worker is already running which adds additional complexity. Keeping the original stock price information is critical for other uses cases. Merging the corrected price and the original price is a critical feature but is used once every x months. Most users only want to see the 3th table for a date range of 7 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did this:

```py
class CorrectedPrice(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = AutoCreatedField()
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
    def _get_correct_prices(self):
        queryset = CorrectedPrice.objects.filter(stock=self.stock)

        return (
            queryset.first()
            .stock.price_set.filter(
                self.timestamp,
                Coalesce(
                    Subquery(
                        queryset.filter(created_at__get(self.timestamp)
                        .order_by("timestamp")
                        values("timestamp")[:1]
                    ),
                    timezone.now()
                ),
            )
        )
        .annotate(
            series=Window(Sum("difference"), order_by=F("timestamp").asc()) + self.value
        )
        .values("timestamp", "series")

    correct_prices = property(_get_correct_prices)
```

Which computes the correct price timeseries as if it was a field of the model every time a CorrectedPrice is queried with the `correct_prices` field. It is computed on the fly just like I needed it.

This solves my problem but with the small drawback that it does not take into account dateranges and might compute a too long timeseries. For this we can resolve the query by adding a limit of instances after `.values("timestamp", "series")` like this: `.values("timestamp", "series")[:1000]`

If the number of elements is equal to 1000 then we can throw an exception that the asked query was too long.